# Unknown object in mysql backup file error

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, mysqladministrator

I am want to restore mysql backup file .
My tables have lots of Blob fields so that its size is approx 3 GB. When I restore 2.5 GB backup file it is restored successfully but I do not understand what is the problem with this.

I also tried to increase **max_allowed_packet** to 100MB to 1024MB but it did not worked...

Suggest me solution if anyone had this error and solved it.

thanks in advance...

Comment: Add some more details on the error, or maybe check out the mySQL forums

Comment: there are no extra information available.... :-(
it only shows small popup of "unknown object in backup file".
max_allowed_packet size worked for many peoples..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your schema tables contains BLOB field then sometimes you will get this error, for this I found one solution:

Restore the backup using command line as follows:

**mysql -u'username' -p'password' < pathOfMyBackup.sql**

this surely solve the problem.